# Error ,coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

Tags: python, django

I am trying to render a template in django but it brings this error in the browser "coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found".It specifically points to line 25 which is code that points to a static file.Here is the code for the template.

base.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<html>
{% block content %}
<head>

</head>
<body ng-app = "{% block ng_app %}example.app.static{% endblock %}">
<div class = "container">
<div class = "content" ng-controller = "{% block ng_controller %}AppController{% endblock %}">
{% verbatim %}
<div class = "panel" ng-repeat = "post in posts">
    <div class = "panel-heading clearfix">
         <h3 class = "panel-title">{{post.title}}</h3>
        <author class ="pull-right">{{post.author.username}}</author>
    </div>
    <p class = "well">{{post.body}}</p>
   </div> 
{% endverbatim %}</div>

{% endblock %}

</div>
{% block js %}
<script src =  "{%static "underscore/underscore.js" %}"></script>
<script src =  "{%static "angular/angular.js" %}"></script>
<script src =  "{%static "angular-resource/angular-resource.js" %}"></script>
<script src =  "{%static "src/js/app.basic.js" %}"></script>
{% endblock %}

</html>
```

[image: Error message in browser]

stacktrace message

[image]

Comment: Need to locate exact porblem. Delete everything form template and leave only `script` tags and see if problem remains. Also add whole trace.

Comment: Deleted everything and still the same error.I have added trace.Also i was working from this tutorial link--(blog.kevinastone.com/getting-started-with-django-rest-framework-and-angularjs.html). You can try and see if you can set it up to run.

Comment: not rendered one. The one that shown in console